# Can't Retrieve Value from GPSTracker Service on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, android-service, android-gps

i am now working on a project that need to get the nearest place from user and sort it in the list view.

All things going well until i get to this step. I have been stuck here for a week and doesn't get any idea how to solve it.

I want to get the longitude and latitude when the program started. I use fragment for it and i want when the user open the fragment, it'll automatically get the latitude and longitude from current user position.

Here i using a Service to get the GPS lat and long. But, it's doesn't work at all. The lat and long always returned with 0 value.

Please master give me some idea how to solve this.
Thanks.

NB this is my GPSTracker.java code

```
public class GPSTrackStandAlone extends Service implements LocationListener {
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Context mContext;
private boolean canGetLocation = false;
private Location mLocation;
private double mLatitude;
private double mLongitude;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 10;
private static final long MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE = 60000;
private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;

public GPSTrackStandAlone(Context mContext) {

    this.mContext = mContext;

}


public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        LocationManager mLocationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        /*getting status of the gps*/
        Boolean isGpsEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        /*getting status of network provider*/
        Boolean isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            /*no location provider enabled*/
        } else {

            this.canGetLocation = true;

            /*getting location from network provider*/
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
                    Log.d("Perms", "Permission for GPS Granted");

                    if (mLocationManager != null) {

                        mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (mLocation != null) {
                            mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                            mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                /*if gps is enabled then get location using gps*/
                if (isGpsEnabled) {
                    if (mLocation == null) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_FOR_UPDATE,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATE, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (mLocationManager != null) {
                            mLocation = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (mLocation != null) {
                                mLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
                                mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return mLocation;
}

/**
 * call this function to stop using gps in your application
 */
public void stopUsingGps() {

    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTrackStandAlone.this);
        }

    }
}

private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
    int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(GPSTrackStandAlone.this, "isGooglePlayServiceAvailable = False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}

protected void createLocationRequest() {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}



public double getLatitude() {
    if (mLocation != null) {

        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        Log.d("MGPS", String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
    }
    return mLongitude;
}

public double getLongitude() {
    Log.d("function", "getLongitude at GPSTrack");

    if (mLocation != null) {

        mLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
        Log.d("MGPS", String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude()));
    }

    return mLongitude;
}


public boolean canGetLocation() {

    return this.canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Comment: does the logcat show "Permission for GPS Granted", or not?

Comment: No sir, that's what i confuse. There are no message or pop up asking for GPS permission.

Comment: you have to code for it to ask for permissions. start here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: yes, before asking here i have add the code for ask permission, but still no message for asking permission appear.

Comment: The "GPS tracker" code has serious flaws which are discussed [in this blog post](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/).

Comment: I don't see the part where you ask for permissions in your code. if it doesn't ask then the problem is not in GPSTracker.